# How to learn these movements?

Tags: tricking

I just watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kjFrcoGC6w

and I really want to learn how to do that. What's the name of these stuff? I'm 26 years old, is it possible to learn this? How to start? if only you can give me the names of this so I can google and look for videos and books on amazon. If you know any, please tell me!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tricking

Answer (score 2):

> What's the name of these stuff?

It's called "tricking"... [wikipedia entry here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricking_%28martial_arts%29).

I don't think it really belongs on this website as IMHO it's not martial arts but acrobatics.

> I'm 26 years old, is it possible to learn this? How to start? if only you can give me the names of this so I can google and look for videos

You'll find *lots* of youtube tutorial videos on tricking: search for "tricking tutorial martial arts".  Still, to get very far I imagine you'd need to find a local group who're into it and join them.  I've no idea how best to approach that beyond the obvious Google searches.

Comment: Yes, it's tricking. But I wouldn't say it's not martial arts. The material is from martial arts, but done in a way that's all its own art and no longer solely for the purpose of martial arts. Contemporary wushu is similar in that respect also, yet it's still thought of as martial arts. And I think many contemporary wushu people go into tricking and vice-versa. There's a lot of overlap, and it's hard to say tricking doesn't have anything to do with martial arts. It certainly does, but that's not its primary focus.

Comment: @SteveWeigand it's about as strongly related to martial arts as Billy Blanks Tae Bo workout... nothing wrong with either if you want acrobatics or a aerobic workout respectively... though for a martial artist to also do Tae Bo would probably be less destructive to their technique than practicing tricking: with Tae Bo you could actually continue to do technique properly if you've the energy, speed and discipline, but the aims of tricking distort the posture, balance, timing, footwork and "flow" of martial arts, undoubtedly developing disruptive habits.

Comment: That's true about the mechanics you described, if they don't already come from a contemporary wushu background before coming into tricking. And the tricking people recognize it and seem to admire it and want to do it the way wushu does it, but they just don't have the right instruction for that. As for it being an aerobic workout, it is to some people but isn't to others. To many people, tricking is martial arts done to an extreme. It's why there aren't a lot of women in it, but you'll see women in gymnastics and wushu all the time. Tricking has the martial vibe to it still, generally.

Comment: Add to that, NASKA has both creative and extreme divisions in weapons and empty hand forms that are very popular, and participated in by both many men AND women. And it is very hard to be good at "tricking" if you aren't already very good at the underlying basics of martial arts. Just because YOU don't like it, doesn't mean it isn't a valid, recognized extension of martial arts.

Comment: @JohnP "Just because YOU don't like it, doesn't mean it isn't a valid, recognized extension of martial arts." - don't put words in my mouth... I don't consider it a martial art because it doesn't aim to optimise fighting ability... nothing to do with likes and dislikes.  What's the rest of what you say got to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a blend of [aerial cartwheels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_cartwheel) and [wushu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pf4HZmfxL04). He's also doing a number of [butterfly twists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHs3DXssjPM), which are common to wushu and [taekwondo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taekwondo).

For strength training I'd [focus on a well rounded program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1789/how-to-establish-a-beginning-weight-program), making sure to include explosive movements such as the [barbell clean](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/OlympicLifts/Clean.html).

However, you're talking about learning a martial art (or gymnastics), which requires specific training. I'd recommend talking to a taekwondo instructor in your area and letting him or her know you want to progress towards aerials.

Comment: This would be primarily wushu, not much of TKD except that some kicks cross over between arts (and are common to almost all karate styled arts). I also voted to move to Martial Arts, although your answer here is pretty much what they would say. You can also tell it's more towards wushu with the brief sword clip.

Comment: This is tricking, not wushu. Wushu does have most or all of the individual techniques demonstrated in this video, but just not done the way they do them. Taekwondo is pretty far removed from tricking, but contemporary Wushu isn't. Barbell cleans and working on power strength training is good and can help in all sorts of ways, but the most direct way of training to do tricking is to find a gymnastics gym which teaches it and sign up for classes. Or find a contemporary (modern) wushu school and train there.

Comment: "Taekwondo is pretty far removed from tricking" - ummm - [there is this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKmnQdn70oY)... :-/

Comment: @TonyD That is not tricking on that video, though. That's Taekwondo done with a little flash for demonstration. The "flash" that they do doesn't even scratch the surface of the kind of flash you see in tricking. That video shows pretty much all orthodox TKD kicks, with some entertaining setups such as stepping on someone who's crouched down and using them as a step to jump off of to get more air. Not in the same league as what they do in tricking.

Answer (score 0):

Age 26 is pretty advanced to begin anything that intensive, unless you are already proficient in some relevant disciplines. Coming from Gymnastics, Taekwondo, Capoeira or Parcours could help with this "tricking", as it apparently borrows freely from all of these. 
If you are not at that level of fitness, consider beginning patiently from any of the above mentioned disciplines. You'll have benefits and fun.